# Proof of Whitney intersection theorem

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

I know "Lectures on the h-cobordism theorem" by Milnor lists a proof. Unfortunately, the proof is subtle, intricate, and lengthy, that is, not succinct and elegant enough (for Milnor, of course.) Is there a more accessible proof? I understand the theorem is intrinsically hard even though the result itself *look* obvious.

Comment: There's a nice discussion in Alexandru Scorpan's *The Wild World of 4-Manifolds*.  I don't recall it being a complete proof, but maybe the absent details can be located elsewhere.

Comment: @squirel: Thank you very much for the information. Yes, I will have a look at it.